# JavaScript timer doesn't resume at specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I got this timer I wrote for myself a while ago. Yesterday I implemented the pause feature, but when I pause it, record paused time and try to pass it again to the new timer - it starts earlier than I paused it. I was digging all day long and how sure where the problem is.

Please help.

P.S. Ignore `/1000`, I need unix timestamp for different purposes =)

```js
var timerId;

function startTimer(started) {
 var localTime = new Date()/1000;

 return setInterval(function() {
  var totalSeconds = ((new Date()/1000) - started);
  var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 3600;

  var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;

  var seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds);
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

  var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  $('.timer .digits').text(timeString);
 }, 1000);
}

$('.start button').click(function() {
 timerId = startTimer(new Date()/1000);
  $('.start').hide().siblings('.pause').show();
});

$('.pause button').click(function() {
  var pausedTime = new Date()/1000;
 clearInterval(timerId);
  $('.timer').data('pausedTime', pausedTime);
  $('.pause').hide().siblings('.resume').show();
});

$('.resume button').click(function() {
  var pausedTime = $('.timer').data('pausedTime');
  timerId = startTimer(pausedTime);
  $('.resume').hide().siblings('.pause').show();
});
```

```css
.pause, .resume {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='timer'>
  <div class='digits'>00:00:00</div>
  <div class='start'><button>Start</button></div>
  <div class='pause'><button>Pause</button></div>
  <div class='resume'><button>Resume</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How much difference between the time when paused, and the time that restarts? Is it hours, minutes, or seconds? You tagged php, but no code showing how you `store paused time in DB` OR `get current time() from PHP as data.current`. Could be an issue between mysql server time, php server time, and browser local time not being the same.

Comment: Please see updated snippet, I eliminated PHP from it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're looking for something like this. Since this is a timer you don't need particular time, just persist elapsed time and get it when resume.

```js
var timerId;

function startTimer() {
 var elapsed = ($('.timer').data('pausedTime') | 0) || 0;

 return setInterval(function() {
  var totalSeconds = elapsed;
  var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 3600;

  var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;

  var seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds);
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

  var timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  $('.timer .digits').text(timeString);
        $('.timer').data('pausedTime', ++elapsed);
 }, 1000);
}

$('.start button').click(function() {
  timerId = startTimer();
  $('.start').hide().siblings('.pause').show();
});

$('.pause button').click(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  $('.pause').hide().siblings('.resume').show();
});

$('.resume button').click(function() {
  timerId = startTimer();
  $('.resume').hide().siblings('.pause').show();
});
```

```css
.pause, .resume {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='timer'>
  <div class='digits'>00:00:00</div>
  <div class='start'><button>Start</button></div>
  <div class='pause'><button>Pause</button></div>
  <div class='resume'><button>Resume</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I definitely need to sync with the clock, using incremented seconds every 1000ms doesn't actually make it identical to a clock time, even in your example the seconds are ticking faster. =) https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/